# C# division with nullable decimal

Tags: c#

Ive got following code:

```
    decimal? Price = 36;
    decimal? ExchangeRate = 4.4m;
    decimal result = Price ?? 0 / ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    //result = 36
    
    decimal cleanExchangeRate = ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1));
    decimal cleanPrice = Price ?? 0;
    decimal result2 =  cleanPrice / cleanExchangeRate;
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
    //result2 = 8.18
```

What is the difference between the first and second calculation? If I do it as one-liner, it somehow doesn't divide the price.

Comment: `decimal result = Price ?? 0 / ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1));` = `decimal result = Price.HasValue ? Price : (0 / ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1)));`

Comment: It's about the order of execution mathematics operations, you should set parentheses in first result ``(Price ?? 0)/....``

Comment: Closing as a typo, this is just a bracketing problem

Comment: Just wanted to throw in: If `Price` does not have a value, shouldn't that reflect on the result? Is that really equivalent to the `Price` being 0? No answer needed, just think about it. It _may_ be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`??` has a very low [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), so the one-liner is parsed as:

```
Price ?? (0 / ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1)));
```

> If `Price` is null, then evaluate to `(0 / ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1)))`, otherwise evaluate to `Price`

You probably meant

```
(Price ?? 0) / ((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1))
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `Price ?? 0` into brackets like that:

```
 decimal result = (Price ?? 0) / (((ExchangeRate == 0) ? 1 : (ExchangeRate ?? 1)));
```

according to your example it means something like that: `Price ?? (0 / ...)`, so because `Price` is not `null`, `result` always would be equal to `Price`

Comment: If you want upvotes: explain _why_ OP should do that.

Comment: Now you got it wrong. If `Price` is non-zero, `result` will be `Price` without accounting for the exchange rate in the original version from question.

Comment: yes I am saying exactly that, actually Price is not zero, that is because 'result' is always equal to 'Price'. But you are right, I'll try to improve my explanation